# Despite having `when()` method it returns null

Tags: java, junit, mockito, mockmvc

I want to test controller method wheter it returns `http status 200`

```
@Slf4j
@Controller
public class AcknowledgeAlertsServiceImpl implements AcknowledgeAlertsService {

    ...

    @Override
    @RequestMapping(value = SERVICE_MAPPING, method = POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity acknowledge(@PathVariable(ALERT_ID) String alertId) {

        ....

        try {
            Map.Entry<AlertID, AlertJTO> entry = cache.findUserEntryById(alertId, userLogin);
            ...
            return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ...
            return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
}
```

I have mocked cache and added `when()` which set `findUserEntryById` to return given entry. Unfortunately it returns a null, do not know why, which going to throw null later and catch "catches". The question is why it is returning null despite setting behaviour what it should return.
The result is http code 400, not 200. I want to pass everything correctly, no matter what is passed.

```
public Map.Entry<AlertID, AlertJTO> findUserEntryById(String alertId, String userLogin) {
        return cache.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(key -> key.getKey()
                        .getUserLogin()
                        .equals(userLogin))
                .filter(entry -> entry.getValue()
                        .getId()
                        .equals(alertId))
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
    }
```

Test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "..." })
@WebAppConfiguration
 public class AcknowledgeAlertsServiceImplTest {

private static final String ALERT_ID = "123";

...

private MockMvc mockMvc;

...
   ...


 @Test
public void acknowledgeOfExistingAlert() throws Exception {
    //given
    UserData userData = mock(UserData.class);
    AlertID alertID = mock(AlertID.class);
    AlertJTO alertJTO = mock(AlertJTO.class);

    Map.Entry<AlertID, AlertJTO> entry = new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(alertID, alertJTO);
    //when
    when(flightmapUserContext.getUserData()).thenReturn(userData);
    when(cache.findUserEntryById(any(),any())).thenReturn(entry);
    //then
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(url(), ALERT_ID)
            .param(AcknowledgeAlertsService.ALERT_ID, ALERT_ID))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status()
                    .isOk());
}
```

Comment: From the code you provided it is not clear where userLogin comes from in real code. Is it equal to "login" from your "when"?

Comment: Same, I don't see any mock that would return "login", you only show it use when call `when(alertsCache.findUserEntryById("123", "login")).thenReturn(entry);`. Just debug `            Map.Entry<AlertID, AlertJTO> entry = alertsCache.findUserEntryById(alertId, userLogin);` and make sure userLogin == "login"

Comment: another option is to replace `when(alertsCache.findUserEntryById("123", "login"))` with `when(alertsCache.findUserEntryById(any(), any()))` - if it works, values are different

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing

```
@InjectMocks
    FlightAcknowledgeAlertsServiceImpl controllerUnderTest;
```

so controller instance doesn't get mocks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Spring's `@MockBean` annotation. Remove `@InjectMocks` and leave just:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(SomeController.class)
public class SomeControllerIT {

  @MockBean
  private AlertsCache alertsCache;

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    when(alertsCache.findUserById(anyLong())).thenReturn(someEntry);
  }
}
```

and do the normal when/thenReturn thing.